# Programmatically change default value for @Column with JPA

Tags: jpa, annotations, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Given that I have a field annotated with @Column, JPA will assign the dafult name on the column in the database from the name of the filed. EG:

```
@Column
private String someString;
```

In this case the column in the DB willbe called SOMESTRING.

I would like that in case there is another annotation on the same field the rules to derive the database column name to be different. For example "_" + FIELDNAME .

EG:

```
@Column
@SpecialColumn
private String someString;
```

In this case the Column name should be : _SOMESTRING

What is the best practice to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that with plain JPA.

At first, it looks like it should be possible with Hibernate though.

Hibernate splits the determination of column names into a two-step process.

1. it determines the "logical" name. Which be default is whatever you provide in an `@Column` annotation.
2. is converting this into a "physical" name. An actual database table column name.

So it sounds like what you are trying to do should be done in the second step, the [`PhysicalNamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy.html).
The problem is though, that the second step doesn't have any information where this data is coming from, so there is no easy way to determine if `@SpecialColumn` is present.

But I guess one could tweak the first step using a custom [`ImplicitNamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy.html) to encode that information in the logical name, e.g. using a suffix.
Unfortunately, that neither gives you easy access to the `Field`, or `Method` where you might find your annotation.
It seems to only make the [`AttributePath`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/source/spi/AttributePath.html) available and I'm not sure if this is sufficient for your purpose. 
But I think it is your only chance.